# Python - sorted list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I got this line of code:

```
my_list = [3,4,7,2,1,6,8,2,1,4]
```

I can sort this list with:

```
my_list.sort()
```

But if I want to create a product list, For example: 2 milks, 3 cookies and so on, if I will sort this list [3,2] I will not be able to know how many milk should I buy or cookies. My question is how can I use dictionary or list so I would be able to sort the list/dictionary and also know the product name after the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends on **how you represent** your product list. Say however we represent it as a list of tupes:

```
product_list = [(2,'milk'),(3,'cookie')]
```

Now you can sort with a `key` and set `reverse` on `True` to sort in *descending* order:

```
product_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

So now we sort on the *first* item of each tuple and we do it in descending order. This will result in:

```
>>> product_list
[(3, 'cookie'), (2, 'milk')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the values in tuples and they will stay together.

```
>>> L = [(3, 'cookies'), (2, 'milk')]
>>> L
[(3, 'cookies'), (2, 'milk')]
>>> L.sort()
>>> L
[(2, 'milk'), (3, 'cookies')]
```

The number must come first as when tuples are compared, first the first element is compared, then the second, etc. This is called lexicographical order.

Comment: Is there any limit for the tuple length for sorting? Just curious.

Comment: @Prajwal nah, as long as the tuple can stay in memory.